# Using an Update Query in MS Access to Update 1 Feild Across 5 Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access, multiple-tables

I have 5 tables that all have 1 field in common and would like to write a query that lets me update the 1 field across the 5 tables all at once. Is this possible?
The 5 table names are as follows and all contain a column named [Firm Name].

```
[Firm Contacts]    
[Firm Addresses]    
[Firms Last Updated]    
[Firm Size]    
[Marketing Groups]
```

So far I have used the Update Query Design View in MS Access to inner join the [Firm Name] field across the 5 tables, however they are only joined to the first table, [Firm Contacts]. I have used the following SQL code to update the records in the first table, [Firm Contacts], however I am not sure how to go about adding language that lets me update the records in the following 4 tables at the same time. The firm names change fairly often and it is a hassle to change them each individually so I am hoping there is a way to do it all at once across the board. In the example below I just made up the firm name "ABCDE" but it should be noted that the firm name "ABCDE" will be the same across all 5 of the tables.

```
UPDATE ((([Firm Contacts] INNER JOIN [Marketing Groups] ON [Firm Contacts].[Firm Name] = [Marketing Groups].[Firm Name]) INNER JOIN [Firms Last Updated] ON [Firm Contacts].[Firm Name] = [Firms Last Updated].[Firm Name]) INNER JOIN [Firm Size] ON [Firm Contacts].[Firm Name] = [Firm Size].[Firm Name]) INNER JOIN [Firm Addresses] ON [Firm Contacts].[Firm Name] = [Firm Addresses].[Firm Name] 
SET [Firm Contacts].[Law Firm] = "ABC"
WHERE ((([Firm Contacts].[Firm Name])="ABCDE"));
```

As a background there may be hundreds of records that share the same [Firm Name] in the [Firm Contact] table, a few in the [Firm Address] table and one in the rest of the tables. I am not sure if this matters or not. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with my problem, as I am not used to using the more advanced features of MS Access or the SQL language in general.

Comment: Are there already relationships between the tables defined?  If so, just set the relationship to cascade update and change the firm names in the parent table, presumably `Firm Contacts` https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/304466/how-to-define-relationships-between-tables-in-an-access-database

Comment: And you just learned a valuable lesson about using natural primary keys instead of surrogate primary keys :-) http://www.agiledata.org/essays/keys.html

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked. I was not aware of how the relationships between tables worked. Because of the links you provided I was able to revamp my Access database and as a result it is much more organized and efficient. Thank you!!!